# order isomorphism between two intervals, where both have minimum and maximum elements

Tags: order-theory

Note to viewers of this question:   I made two attempts to construct an isomorphism between [0,1) and a larger interval.  My original posting had some typos that made the two answers I received hard to follow.  So, I took another  my typo-less definitions of the two alleged isomorphisms, and I realize that the answer I received from James is  still valid:  Neither of my alleged isomorphisms work.  I will explain why I agree with the given answer in my comment.

--- original question ----

I am looking at a problem which asks if there is an order isomorphism between the two sets A and D (both subsets of the rationals, Q), as defined below:

A = {  $1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ }

D = {  $1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ }  $\cup$ {  $2 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ }

Note: $n \epsilon \Bbb N$

I answered yes because I did not realize that  A does not include 1, whereas the set D does.  When n=0, then  the following expression in the definition of D:

$2 - \frac{1}{n+1}$

becomes

$2 - \frac{1}{0+1}$

which is 1. So 1 is part of set D.   This means A lacks a maximum element while D has one. So, no order isomorphism here.

Then I got to thinking  (and that's when trouble usually starts for me ;^):   *what if* we defined A and D as follows:

A = {  $1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ }    $  \cup$ {1}

D =  {  $1 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ } $\cup$ {  $2 - \frac{1}{n+1}$ }  $  \cup $ {2}

And then we defined a bijection (at least I think it would be a bijection) 'g' as follows:

g(n) =

$1 - \frac{1}{\frac{n}{2} +1}$     -- if n is even and $n \gt 0$

$1 - \frac{1}{\frac{n-1}{2} +1}$       -- if n is odd

$n \epsilon \Bbb N$

With the revised A and D both now have maximum elements. And I believe my bijection from A to D will hit all points on D and is 1-1.    But I am hoping wiser minds than mine might weigh in. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You are correct that your original $A$ does not have a maximum element, but neither does $D$? They are order isomorphic by the function from $A$ to $B$ that adds $1$ right?

Comment: I mean, one set is a translation of the other, and translations preserve order.

Comment: I'm sorry James..  I did not copy the problem correctly.  (I am working from 'Classic Set Theory' / Goldrei..  I will fix it now.

Comment: OK. I fixed it.  In the book it says that the fact that 1 is in A, but not in D makes A and D not order isomorphic. I think I my revised A and D are order isomorphic. Please let me know what you think.. and thanks for your response !

Comment: It is yet to be fixed as $D$ is now a union of a set with itself.

Comment: It would also help notation if you told us what you want $n$ to range over: The non-negative, or the positive integers. (It is unlikely to actually change any of the answers though).

Comment: re: >>It is yet to be fixed as D is now a union of a set with itself. <<   Yikes.. OK.. I will not hit 'submit' on these questions at 2 AM any more.   Fixed it. apologies for double typo.

Comment: My answer is still correct. Furthermore $g$ is still not well defined and $n\notin A$ for most $n$. Your definition should look something like $g(x) = \begin{cases} \text{blah} & \text{if } x = 1-\frac{1}{2n} \\ \text{blah} & \ldots\end{cases}$.

Now, the fixed old $D$ **still** doesn't have a maximum element. It is true that the old $A$ and $D$ are not isomorphic but you can't prove that by claiming that $D$ has a maximum, because it doesn't. $D$ does, however, have elements with infinitely many things smaller than it, which $A$ does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent of you fixing the old $A$ and $D$, your new $A$ and $D$ are not order-isomorphic:

$A$ is order-isomorphic to $\omega+1$ (i.e. you have something that looks like the natural numbers, with something stuck on top) where as $D$ is order isomorphic to $\omega + \omega + 1$ i.e. you have two copies of the natural numbers, one bigger than the other, and an element on top.

You can even see more. As both $A$ and $D$ have a least element, $0$, any order isomorphism between $A$ and $D$ sends $0$ to $0$. Then, inductively, everything of the form $1 - \frac{1}{n}$ in $A$ has to be sent to $1 - \frac{1}{n}$ in $D$ (these are both the least elements of what is left). Then after this, all you have left in $A$ is the top element, however you have a lot more things left in $D$, hence, an isomorphism can't exist (you can however embed $A$ as an initial segment of $D$ by mapping $1$ to $1$).

The $g$ you have written is not $1-1$ as it sends $2$ and $3$ to the same thing (supposing you mean what I think you mean). It's possible you were trying to send "even" $1-\frac{1}{2n}\mapsto 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ and "odd" $1-\frac{1}{2n + 1} \mapsto 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ but this isn't order preserving.

Comment: James, After fixing my typos, I re-read your answer, and it makes sense to me.  I was trying to send  'even'  to 1-1/n,  and 'odd' to 2-1/n, and i kind of made a mess of things.  But even if I did it correctly it would NOT be order preserving,as you pointed out.  So, thanks again, I'm accepting your answer... sorry for the bumps in the road on the way .. but this helped my understanding of order isomorphisms a lot. - cb

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, $g$ is not defined, because you haven't specified what $x$ and $n$ have to do with each other.

Neither $A$ nor $D$ have a maximum element--$1$ is less than infinitely-many elements of $D$--and adding one in will not make them order isomorphic. The kicker, here, is that $1$ is a *limit element* of $D$, while $A$ has no such element--all of the elements of $A$ are either the initial element or an immediate successor.